# Python: Permutations

Tags: python, substring, permutation

I am working on [a problem](https://buildingai.elementsofai.com/Getting-started-with-AI/optimization), where I want to get all permutations, but am not permitted to  modify the print statement. I am also not permitted to  use `itertools` or other packages.

Instuctions:

> In order for the program to list out all possible routes it needs some work. Fix the program by adding an if statement that checks that the route includes all of the ports. In other words, check that each of the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 are included in the list route. Note that it isn't necessary to check that no port appears twice because if that were the case, then the route couldn't include all the five ports.

> You do not need to change the print statement.

This is my code, but **it doesn't work**. How can this be fixed?

```
def main():
    portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]

    # don't change this bit - provided in exercise
    port1 = 0
    for port2 in range(1, 5):
        for port3 in range(1, 5):
            for port4 in range(1, 5):
                for port5 in range(1, 5):
                    route = [port1, port2, port3, port4, port5]

                    # instructions to add if statement that checks that the route includes all of the ports
                    # if "PAN" in route and "AMS" in route and "CAS" in route and "NYC" in route and "HEL" in route:
                    if all([val in route for val in portnames]):
                    
                        # do not modify the print statement
                        print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in route]))

                    else:
                        continue

main()
```

Comment: What restrictions? I'm on my phone (making links super annoying) and this question might outlive that link. Please make the question self-contained

Comment: You need to be more specific about what doesn't work. What is the expected output? What output are you getting?

Comment: A hint is that your `route` is just a list of numbers at the moment. They need to be port names. `for port1 in portnames:` etc.

Comment: I assume that I can't use 'itertools' as there is the last line restriction (not changing it), but also it would be too easy. Plus they have already provided most of the code.

Comment: Can't use 'itertools' @chepner

Comment: @william3031 You said you couldn't use `itertools` because you don't know how to modify a `print` statement. That statement doesn't care if `route` comes from `product` or your manual loop. (That said, I've delete my comment because it didn't take into account the fixed value of `port1`.)

Comment: I've edited the question to note that I am 'not permitted' to use 'itertools' rather than 'can't' use it. Also edited to show what has been provided and what has been added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the following `print` statement before the `if` condition shows the error:

```
# code before
    print(route)
    if all([val in route for val in portnames]):
# code after


# Output:
# [0, 4, 3, 2, 2]
# [0, 4, 3, 2, 3]
# [0, 4, 3, 2, 4]
# ...
```

`route` is made up of integers generated by `range`. You can instead make your `if` statement:

```
if all([portnames.index(val) in route for val in portnames]):
```

Output:

```
PAN AMS CAS NYC HEL
PAN AMS CAS HEL NYC
PAN AMS NYC CAS HEL
PAN AMS NYC HEL CAS
PAN AMS HEL CAS NYC
PAN AMS HEL NYC CAS
PAN CAS AMS NYC HEL
PAN CAS AMS HEL NYC
PAN CAS NYC AMS HEL
PAN CAS NYC HEL AMS
PAN CAS HEL AMS NYC
PAN CAS HEL NYC AMS
PAN NYC AMS CAS HEL
PAN NYC AMS HEL CAS
PAN NYC CAS AMS HEL
PAN NYC CAS HEL AMS
PAN NYC HEL AMS CAS
PAN NYC HEL CAS AMS
PAN HEL AMS CAS NYC
PAN HEL AMS NYC CAS
PAN HEL CAS AMS NYC
PAN HEL CAS NYC AMS
PAN HEL NYC AMS CAS
PAN HEL NYC CAS AMS
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that work if I don't modify `print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in route]))` though?

Comment: @william3031 yes, the last output is from your code copy/pasted with just the `if` statement modified.  The additional `print` statement I described is unnecessary - I only included it for illustration

Comment: So the routes are numeric, while I am trying to match strings and the if statement should change?

Comment: @william3031 exactly, the multiple `range` calls are generating integer positions of `portnames`, so you can use `index()` to link those positions to the strings themselves

Answer (score 1):

You can do this instead of a list comprehension -

```
if set(range(len(portnames))).issubset(route)
```

The set of routes (which are indexes from 0-4) must be completely a contain the set of the portnames' indices (0-4). If this is `True`, then every portname will exist in the route and thus printed.

```
portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]

# don't change this bit - provided in exercise
port1 = 0
for port2 in range(1, 5):
    for port3 in range(1, 5):
        for port4 in range(1, 5):
            for port5 in range(1, 5):
                route = [port1, port2, port3, port4, port5]

                # instructions to add if statement that checks that the route includes all of the ports
                # if "PAN" in route and "AMS" in route and "CAS" in route and "NYC" in route and "HEL" in route:
                if set(range(len(portnames))).issubset(route):

                    # do not modify the print statement
                    print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in route]))

                else:
                    continue
```

```
PAN AMS CAS NYC HEL
PAN AMS CAS HEL NYC
PAN AMS NYC CAS HEL
PAN AMS NYC HEL CAS
PAN AMS HEL CAS NYC
PAN AMS HEL NYC CAS
PAN CAS AMS NYC HEL
PAN CAS AMS HEL NYC
PAN CAS NYC AMS HEL
PAN CAS NYC HEL AMS
PAN CAS HEL AMS NYC
PAN CAS HEL NYC AMS
PAN NYC AMS CAS HEL
PAN NYC AMS HEL CAS
PAN NYC CAS AMS HEL
PAN NYC CAS HEL AMS
PAN NYC HEL AMS CAS
PAN NYC HEL CAS AMS
PAN HEL AMS CAS NYC
PAN HEL AMS NYC CAS
PAN HEL CAS AMS NYC
PAN HEL CAS NYC AMS
PAN HEL NYC AMS CAS
PAN HEL NYC CAS AMS
```

Comment: There are duplicates, e.g. in the line of the output, `AMS` is in there four times. `AssertionError: False != True : Incorrect set of route combinations`

Comment: updated it .. accidently swapped the code

Answer (score 1):

```
def main():
    portnames = ["PAN", "AMS", "CAS", "NYC", "HEL"]
    # https://sea-distances.org/
    # nautical miles converted to km
    D = [
            [0,8943,8019,3652,10545],
            [8943,0,2619,6317,2078],
            [8019,2619,0,5836,4939],
            [3652,6317,5836,0,7825],
            [10545,2078,4939,7825,0]
        ]
    # https://timeforchange.org/co2-emissions-shipping-goods
    # assume 20g per km per metric ton (of pineapples)
    co2 = 0.020
    route = []
    port1 = 0
    for port2 in range(1,5):
                for port3 in range(1,5):
                    for port4 in range(1,5):
                        for port5 in range(1,5):
                            result = [port1, port2, port3, port4, port5]
                            if 0 in result:
                                if 1 in result:
                                    if 2 in result:
                                        if 3 in result:
                                            if 4 in result:
                                                route.append(result)
    for singleRoute in route:
        distance = D[singleRoute[0]][singleRoute[1]] + D[singleRoute[1]][singleRoute[2]] + D[singleRoute[2]][singleRoute[3]] + D[singleRoute[3]][singleRoute[4]]
        emissions = distance * co2      
        print(' '.join([portnames[i] for i in singleRoute]) + " %.1f kg" % emissions)
main()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

a pro style tip: you can check that the route includes all ports (numbered 0, 1, ..., 4) easily by using Python sets. The clumsy if statement in the example solution can be replaced by the much more elegant one:

if set(route) == set(range(5)):